# message "You wanted to install version 5.6.30" on Mac

Tags: php, bash, apache

can anyone help me please ?

I simply try to update the PHP version on my Mac but I really don't understand my Apache configuration. I get the message 
"Package 5.6-10.10-frontenddev is already installed at version 5.6.30-20170506-093822. You wanted to install version 5.6.30".

How i can resolve it ? Thank you for your help.
PS: I'm new on this forum, so excuse-me if i committed errors. ;-)

Comment: Are you using `Homebrew` as your package manager? Please give us the steps you followed to upgrade PHP.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to downgrade your version?

Comment: Lol effectively with a package manager, i think that'll be better. thanks guys